# How do I tell GTK to update application externally?

Tags: c, gtk3

### Context and Question

For reasons, I need to fork my code and update a variable on both forks.  The variable is stored in memory via `mmap` so it is accessible to all processes.  On one child process, I increment the variable.  How do I tell the GTK application to refresh/update/redraw from the child process?

### MWE

```
/*
 * Update GTK label from variable stored in mmap
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer localval) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    // Button Containers
    GtkWidget *button_box_quit;
    // Buttons
    GtkWidget *exit_button;
    // Text
    GtkWidget *text_status;
    
    // Define Window, dynamic size for screen.
    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "test");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300);
    
    // Define Button Boxes.
    button_box_quit = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    
    // Define Exit Button, put it in a box, put box in window
    exit_button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Exit");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (button_box_quit), exit_button);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box_quit);

    // Connect signals to buttons
    g_signal_connect_swapped (exit_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
    
    // Define text status
    char msg[32]={0};
    // The "print" line
    g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", *(int *)localval);
    text_status = gtk_label_new(msg);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (button_box_quit), text_status);
    
    //Activate!
    g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", *(int *)localval);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(text_status), msg);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;
    
    int *VAL = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    int *ABORT = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    int pid = fork();
    
    if (pid == 0) {
        while(!*ABORT) {
            printf("%d\n", *VAL);
            // Increments here should be reflected outside this PID.
            *VAL = *VAL + 1;
            usleep(1000000);
        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
        // The passing line
        g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), VAL);
        status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
        g_object_unref (app);
        *ABORT = 1;
    }
    *ABORT = 1;
    return status;
}
```

### What happens at runtime

When the MWE is run, the terminal dutifully prints the value each time it updates.  However, the GTK window forever says "val: 1".  We can tell the value stored in mmap is accessible to the GTK process by adding `usleep(3000000)` in the `activate` process just before `gtk_widget_show_all`.  In this variant, the window will forever show "val: 4".

### The Question Reiterated

How do I make the output on the GTK window match the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `activate` is called only once (when the window is loaded/activated) but nothing is refreshing the label once loaded, I did some changes in the code (using a global, very ugly but simple to ilustrate the problem), the "Exit Button" is now a  "Refresh Button". Press it and you will see the changes in `VAL`.

```
/*
 * Update GTK label from variable stored in mmap
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkWidget *text_status;

static void refresh(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    (void)widget;

    char msg[32]={0};

    g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", *(int *)data);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(text_status), msg);
}

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer localval) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    // Button Containers
    GtkWidget *button_box_quit;
    // Buttons
    GtkWidget *refresh_button;
    // Text


    // Define Window, dynamic size for screen.
    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "test");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300);

    // Define Button Boxes.
    button_box_quit = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);



    // Define Exit Button, put it in a box, put box in window
    refresh_button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Refresh");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (button_box_quit), refresh_button);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box_quit);

    // Connect signals to buttons
    g_signal_connect(refresh_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (refresh), localval);

    // Define text status
    char msg[32]={0};
    // The "print" line
    g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", *(int *)localval);
    text_status = gtk_label_new(msg);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (button_box_quit), text_status);

    //Activate!
    g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", *(int *)localval);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(text_status), msg);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    int *VAL = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    int *ABORT = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        while(!*ABORT) {
            printf("%d\n", *VAL);
            // Increments here should be reflected outside this PID.
            *VAL = *VAL + 1;
            usleep(1000000);
        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
        // The passing line
        g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), VAL);
        status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
        g_object_unref (app);
        *ABORT = 1;
    }
    *ABORT = 1;
    return status;
}
```

If you want to refresh the label without pressing a button, you can use [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) and set a function to be called at regular intervals refreshing `VAL`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this working solution.  I tried something similar earlier, but I did not include the crucial ``(void)widget``.  Unfortunately, porting this answer to one which uses ``g_timeout_add`` is not straightforward.  I played around and figured something out which works for that.  I will post that as a separate answer for folks that encounter similar challenges in the future.

Comment: You are welcome, well ..., `(void)widget;` is not crucial at all, is just to inform the compiler that a parameter is not used and avoids a warning.

Answer (score 2):

### `g_timeout_add` solution

To allow for an automatic update of the main loop from the application we can use `g_timeout_add` as @David Ranieri pointed out.  However, the API of GTK3 requires we pass the `refresh` function slightly differently to `g_timeout_add`.

Modifying the OP MWE and @David Ranieri's answer:

```
/*
 * Update GTK label from variable stored in mmap
 * Timeout Method
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkWidget *text_status;

static gboolean refresh(gpointer data) {
    char msg[32]={0};

    g_snprintf(msg, sizeof msg, "val: %d\n", *(int *)data);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(text_status), msg);

    return TRUE;
}

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer localval) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    // Button Containers
    GtkWidget *button_box_quit;
    // Buttons
    GtkWidget *exit_button;

    // Define Window, dynamic size for screen.
    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "test");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300);

    // Define Button Boxes.
    button_box_quit = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);

    // Define Exit Button, put it in a box, put box in window
    exit_button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Exit");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (button_box_quit), exit_button);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box_quit);

    // Connect signals to buttons
    g_signal_connect_swapped (exit_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);

    // Define text status
    text_status = gtk_label_new(NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (button_box_quit), text_status);

    // Define timeout
    g_timeout_add(500, G_SOURCE_FUNC(refresh), localval);

    // Activate!
    refresh(localval);
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    int *VAL = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    int *ABORT = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        while(!*ABORT) {
            printf("%d\n", *VAL);
            // Increments here should be reflected outside this PID.
            *VAL = *VAL + 1;
            usleep(1000000);
        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
        // The passing line
        g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), VAL);
        status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
        g_object_unref (app);
        *ABORT = 1;
    }
    *ABORT = 1;
    return status;
}
```

The important differences:

- We no longer pass the empty widget to refresh like we do when using a callback.
- GTK3 must be explicitly told that `refresh` is a `G_SOURCE_FUNC`.

Comment: Nice, to have the code a little cleaner in production I would reuse `refresh()` in the _// define text status_ section: https://ideone.com/uSI9er

Comment: I will also put the `g_time_add()` line after creating the `text_status` widget, notice that if the callback is executed before creating the widget it will crash inside `refresh` (for example if one day you switch from 500 milliseconds to 50 milliseconds)

Comment: Cleaned up in edit per your suggestions.  I'm running on a Raspberry Pi, so I don't observe the crash with the timeout reduction.  Creating even a simple GTK window takes longer than 1s.  For fast machines when using this example, adding a startup delay may be worthwhile.